# Find the couples of numbers in the same row which are in common with 2 days

Tags: php, mysql

```
1|24-jan-11|n1|89|17|81|6|40
2|24-jan-11|n1|21|15|42|67|11
3|24-jan-11|n1|31|17|45|70|69
4|24-jan-11|n1|74|88|47|56|14

5|28-jan-11|n2|31|25|75|37|84
6|28-jan-11|n2|15|4|20|34|68
7|28-jan-11|n2|19|15|81|14|67
8|28-jan-11|n2|47|17|15|71|14
```

I have a MySQL table containing an array of numbers for each day (*above are shown the numbers of January 24, 2011 and January 28, 2011*). Each number is any number between `1 and 90`.
I need to find the couples of numbers in the same row which are in common with 2 days.

**For example:**

```
row #2 (January 24, 2011) contains 15 and 67
row #7 (January 28, 2011) also contains 15 and 67

row #4 (January 24, 2011) contains 47 and 14
row #8 (January 28, 2011) also contains 47 and 14
```

**The script should return:**

```
"15" and "67" in the row "2" and "7"
"47" and "14" in the row "4" and "8"
```

My solution was to parse all the numbers in the table with a PHP loop. The problem is that it would take much time and the server would crash.

Is there any math formula or quick PHP/mySQL function I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: do you store each number in a row? I mean something like
`date | N|n1|n2| ..`
`28-jan-11 |n1|15|18| ..`

Comment: Show us what you've tried (the PHP loop that was crashing) already.

Comment: Your columns suffer from having no names.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it in pure SQL just for fun, it's up to you to decide if it's performant enough :)

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable
    (`id` int, `date` varchar(9), `col1` varchar(2), `col2` int, `col3` int, `col4` int, `col5` int, `col6` int)
;

INSERT INTO yourTable
    (`id`, `date`, `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`, `col5`, `col6`)
VALUES
    (1, '24-jan-11', 'n1', 89, 17, 81, 6, 40),
    (2, '24-jan-11', 'n1', 21, 15, 42, 67, 11),
    (3, '24-jan-11', 'n1', 31, 17, 45, 70, 69),
    (4, '24-jan-11', 'n1', 74, 88, 47, 56, 14),
    (5, '28-jan-11', 'n2', 31, 25, 75, 37, 84),
    (6, '28-jan-11', 'n2', 15, 4, 20, 34, 68),
    (7, '28-jan-11', 'n2', 19, 15, 81, 14, 67),
    (8, '28-jan-11', 'n2', 47, 17, 15, 71, 14)
;
```

And here it comes:

```
select
yt1.id, yt2.id,
case when yt1.col2 in (yt2.col2, yt2.col3, yt2.col4, yt2.col5, yt2.col6) then yt1.col2 else null end c1,
case when yt1.col3 in (yt2.col2, yt2.col3, yt2.col4, yt2.col5, yt2.col6) then yt1.col3 else null end c2,
case when yt1.col4 in (yt2.col2, yt2.col3, yt2.col4, yt2.col5, yt2.col6) then yt1.col4 else null end c3,
case when yt1.col5 in (yt2.col2, yt2.col3, yt2.col4, yt2.col5, yt2.col6) then yt1.col5 else null end c4,
case when yt1.col6 in (yt2.col2, yt2.col3, yt2.col4, yt2.col5, yt2.col6) then yt1.col6 else null end c5
from
yourTable yt1
,yourTable yt2 
where
yt1.date = '24-jan-11'
and yt2.date = '28-jan-11'
and
(
yt1.col2 in (yt2.col2, yt2.col3, yt2.col4, yt2.col5, yt2.col6)
or yt1.col3 in (yt2.col2, yt2.col3, yt2.col4, yt2.col5, yt2.col6)
or yt1.col4 in (yt2.col2, yt2.col3, yt2.col4, yt2.col5, yt2.col6)
or yt1.col5 in (yt2.col2, yt2.col3, yt2.col4, yt2.col5, yt2.col6)
or yt1.col6 in (yt2.col2, yt2.col3, yt2.col4, yt2.col5, yt2.col6)
)
having 
case when c1 is null then 0 else 1 end 
+ case when c2 is null then 0 else 1 end 
+ case when c3 is null then 0 else 1 end 
+ case when c4 is null then 0 else 1 end 
+ case when c5 is null then 0 else 1 end 
>= 2
```

Comment: Man! If this works the rest of my day is going to be spent understanding it... :) What is the average query time?

Comment: What do I know? With the test data it took 0.062 seconds on my crappy VM

Answer (score 0):

*"Is there any math formula..."* No - you haven't give us any rules as to how the numbers came to be so as far as I can see the only way to do this is to go ahead and compare every combination.  That said, there are things you can do to speed things up - and equally pitfalls which will kill a script.  Since you haven't given us any code to working with I'm just going to lay out a procedural solution.

---

**Rules of the Game**

- As I understand it you have 2 variables (arrays) - one for each day.
- I don't know the significance (if any) of "n1" and "n2" so I'm ignoring them.
- You are only interested in common values between the two days/dates and don't care about any pairs which may be found within the same date.

In this example your days will be represented by the variables `$day[0]` and `$day[1]` - so you don't repeat yourself (and end up in a time-consuming loop), you probably want to iterate over one of the days and compute all possible combinations of pairs for each row.  For ease of lookup these combinations will be used as array keys and will map to the corresponding row ID.  Eg.

```
$pairs = array();
foreach($days[0] as $day){
  $len = count($day);
  for($i=3;$i<$len;$i++)
    for($j=$i+1;$j<$len;$j++){
      $key = $day[$j] > $day[$i] ? "{$day[$i]}|{$day[$j]}" 
                                 : "{$day[$j]}|{$day[$i]}";
      $pairs[$key] = $day[0];
    }
}
```

Note that to avoid having to duplicate array keys depending on the order in which combinations are "found" I've specified that keys be set in numerical order.  Once we have this array of pre-computed pairs it's then easier to make a pass over the second day and determine what values it has in common.  Eg.

```
foreach($days[1] as $day){
  $len = count($day);
  for($i=3;$i<$len;$i++)
    for($j=$i+1;$j<$len;$j++){
      $key = $day[$j] > $day[$i] ? "{$day[$i]}|{$day[$j]}" 
                                 : "{$day[$j]}|{$day[$i]}";
      if(isset($pairs[$key]))
        echo "\"{$day[$i]}\" and \"{$day[$j]}\" in the row "
          .  "\"{$pairs[$key]}\" and \"{$day[0]}\"<br/>";
    }
}
```

[working example](http://ideone.com/czIxju)

I'll leave it up to you to prettify the solution, I'm not sure how it will scale to large datasets but I've given you enough to work with - you can always make use of [`set_time_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) If you are working with particularly large arrays.

Answer (score 0):

A pure SQL version of it. Just like tombom, for fun.

This is assuming that you data is in a single pipe delimited field as you original post suggests.

This is a single piece of SQL, which relies on an extra table of integers (called integers, with 1 column called i, and 10 rows with the values from 0 to 9):-

```
SELECT DISTINCT SubA.TheDate, SubB.TheDate, SubA.TheRowNum, SubB.TheRowNum, SubA.aDelimitedSection, SubB.aDelimitedSection, SubC.aDelimitedSection, SubD.aDelimitedSection,
CONCAT('"', SubA.aDelimitedSection, '" and "', SubC.aDelimitedSection, '" in the row "', SubA.TheRowNum, '" and "', SubB.TheRowNum, '"')
FROM (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SomeField, '|', 1) TheRowNum, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SomeField, '|', 2), '|', -1) TheDate, SomeField, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(SomeField, '|'), '|', Sub1.AnInt), '|', -1) AS aDelimitedSection, Sub1.AnInt
FROM StatsTest,
(SELECT 4+a.i+b.i*10 AS AnInt FROM integers a, integers b) Sub1
WHERE Sub1.AnInt <= (1 + LENGTH(SomeField) - LENGTH( REPLACE ( SomeField, "|", "")))) SubA
INNER JOIN (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SomeField, '|', 1) TheRowNum, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SomeField, '|', 2), '|', -1) TheDate, SomeField, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(SomeField, '|'), '|', Sub1.AnInt), '|', -1) AS aDelimitedSection, Sub1.AnInt
FROM StatsTest,
(SELECT 4+a.i+b.i*10 AS AnInt FROM integers a, integers b) Sub1
WHERE Sub1.AnInt <= (1 + LENGTH(SomeField) - LENGTH( REPLACE ( SomeField, "|", "")))) SubB
ON SubA.aDelimitedSection = SubB.aDelimitedSection AND SubA.TheRowNum < SubB.TheRowNum AND SubA.TheDate != SubB.TheDate
INNER JOIN (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SomeField, '|', 1) TheRowNum, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SomeField, '|', 2), '|', -1) TheDate, SomeField, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(SomeField, '|'), '|', Sub1.AnInt), '|', -1) AS aDelimitedSection, Sub1.AnInt
FROM StatsTest,
(SELECT 4+a.i+b.i*10 AS AnInt FROM integers a, integers b) Sub1
WHERE Sub1.AnInt <= (1 + LENGTH(SomeField) - LENGTH( REPLACE ( SomeField, "|", "")))) SubC
ON SubA.aDelimitedSection < SubC.aDelimitedSection AND SubA.TheRowNum = SubC.TheRowNum
INNER JOIN (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SomeField, '|', 1) TheRowNum, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SomeField, '|', 2), '|', -1) TheDate, SomeField, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(SomeField, '|'), '|', Sub1.AnInt), '|', -1) AS aDelimitedSection, Sub1.AnInt
FROM StatsTest,
(SELECT 4+a.i+b.i*10 AS AnInt FROM integers a, integers b) Sub1
WHERE Sub1.AnInt <= (1 + LENGTH(SomeField) - LENGTH( REPLACE ( SomeField, "|", "")))) SubD
ON SubC.aDelimitedSection = SubD.aDelimitedSection AND SubB.TheRowNum = SubD.TheRowNum
```

Takes 0.014 seconds on xampp on my machine with your test data, but not sure it is really scaleable